# Create multidimensional Array php without repetitive

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying create a multidimensional array but I have the result I want jajaja, this is my code.

All the vars are dynamically created.

```
foreach ($list_items as $key => $level):
        foreach ($list_songs as $k =>$attribute):
            $variables[$level][$k] = $attribute; // changed $variables[] to $variables[$level][]
            endforeach;
endforeach;
```

This is for create the muldimensional i have this results when print this:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($list_items,1) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($list_songs,1) . '</pre>';    
echo '<pre>' . print_r($variables,1) . '</pre>';  

/*THIS IS THE ARRAY $list_items */

Array
(
  [0] => item_name_1
  [1] => item_name_2
)

/*THIS IS THE ARRAY $list_songs*/
Array
(
  [0] => Musica Ligera
  [1] => La chispa adecuada
)

/*THIS IS THE ARRAY $variables*/

Array
(
[item_name_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Musica Ligera
        [1] => La chispa adecuada
    )

[item_name_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Musica Ligera
        [1] => La chispa adecuada
    )

 )
```

I understand the problem, because I am save all the keys for the songs in each key in list items but I don't know how resolve it I want this in the result:

```
Array
(
[item_name_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Musica Ligera
    )

[item_name_2] => Array
    (
        [1] => La chispa adecuada
    )

 )
```

All the comments is welcome, regards :D

Comment: I can't picture a simple way to do this without manual iteration, plus there's not a problem with doing that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case the length of two arrays are same, so use a for loop instead.

```
    for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_items); $i++ ){
         $variables[$list_items[$i]][array_keys($list_songs)[$i]] = $list_songs[$i];
    }
    print_r($variables);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [item_name_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => song1
        )

    [item_name_2] => Array
        (
            [1] => song2
        )

)
```